# What are all possible usages of "Should have done" & "Should have been doing" & "Should be doing"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> **You should have done it.**
>
> **You should have been doing.**
>
> **You should be doing it.**

It is almost confusing.

1. When we say **You should have done it** , does it always mean that you were supposed to do it but you did not do?
   Can it also mean as an equivalent to "**you would have done**" or "**you will have done**" ? Could you list all possible useages of the "**You should have done**" , please?
2. What are all possible usages of "**should have been doing**"  , rather than possibility in the future?

Comment: "You should have been doing" must also have **it** or **that** or **this** at the end, otherwise it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

**"You should have done it."** always mean that you were supposed to finish it. Whether you actually did it is not stated.

Is it an equivalent to:

- "you would have done" - no, this implies a missed opportunity
- "you will have done" - no, this implies experience

The exact meaning would depend on a full sentence context..

Examples:

- You should have done research before asking this question, did you?
- You would have done a lot of algebra review if you had taken pre-calculus.
- You will have done this type of problem before because you are an advanced student.

**"You should have been doing (it)"** means you were supposed to be working on or participating in an activity. This phrase also does not state whether or not you were doing it or not.

Examples:

- You should have been doing your homework. Were you? Have you finished it yet?
- You should have been more careful.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "**Should have done it**", it means pretty much what you said "*you were supposed to do it*", and it generally implies that "*you did not do it*".

> I was supposed to clean the dishes last night, but I forgot to.

But it is possible that you were "*supposed to do it",* **(and)** *you did do it*.

> I was supposed to do the dishes last night, so I did.

Now I guess it could also mean you "*Would have done it*", (and didn't).

> I was supposed to do the dishes last night, and I would have, but I was gone all night.

Now to answer you other question about when to use "**You should have done it", "You should have been doing it",** and **"You should be doing it".** The answer is about tenses.

> You should have done it. (Past tense) (*In the past* you should have done it).
>
> You should have been doing it. (Present perfect continues tense) (*In the past* you should have been (*In that present*) doing it).
>
> You should be doing it. (present tense) (*In the present* you should be doing it)